# LinkedIn Authorization Screen Not Appearing

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sdk, linkedin-api

I have integrated official LinkedIn iOS SDK(https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#iossdk). While clicking on "Share via LinkedIn" in my iOS app, it opens LinkedIn official iOS app on my iOS device & ask for login, but after logging **user stays on LinkedIn App only not coming back to my iOS App** & **no authorization screen displayed**. (I am using iPad with iOS 8 & 9) Is there any suggestion?

My Plist Settings to configure Linkedin:
[image]

Sample Code:

```
-(void)postOnLinkedIn:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictData {

NSMutableDictionary *dictCode = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"anyone",@"code", nil];
[dictData setObject:@"Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG" forKey:@"comment"];
[dictData setObject:dictCode forKey:@"visibility"];

NSString *url = @"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares";
NSString *payload = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dictData];
NSLog(@"%@",payload);

//    NSString *payload = [NSString initWithString:@"{
//                         \"comment\":\"Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG\",
//                         \"visibility\":{ \"code\":\"anyone\" }
//                         }"];

if ([LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession]) {
    [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] postRequest:url stringBody:payload
                                         success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response) {
                                             // do something with response
                                         }
                                           error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {
                                               // do something with error
                                           }];
}
else {
    [self connectToLinkedIn];
}
}




-(void)connectToLinkedIn {
[LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION,LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION, nil]
                                     state:@"state"
                    showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES
                              successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {

                                  NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
                                  LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
                                  NSLog(@"value=%@ isvalid=%@",[session value],[session isValid] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
                              }
                                errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                    //[self clearSession:<#(id)#>]
                                    NSLog(@"%s %@","error called! ", [error description]);
                                    //self.lastError = error;
                                    //  _responseLabel.text = [error description];
                                    //[self updateControlsWithResponseLabel:YES];
                                }
 ];
}
```

Comment: could you edit your question to show how you are calling the "Share via LinkedIn" API via your code?

Comment: I have updated the post. Let me know anything else needed. Thanks.

Comment: If I run the same code on "iPhone - 4(iOS 7)", It worked fine. It opens "LinkedIn Authorization Screen". Thanks.

Comment: I got the same issue when trying to login with LinkedIn. It only happens on my iPad, on my iPhone it works fine. Both run iOS 9.

Comment: hi @Rahul have you fixed this issue? I have the save problem.

Comment: @Arpit: Sorry, I could not find any proper solution yet. So, please update if anybody finds anything. Thanks.